# Parse XML document in java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I want to find the `@name` from table tag, from given `col_alt`. Can anybody
help me with this.
Is it possible with `javax.XML.Xpath`? If not can you suggest the
other way to find this.

This is the example of XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mapping>
    <table name="CLIENT">
        <table_column>
            <column name="CLIENT_NAME">
                <col_alt>CLIENT_NAME</col_alt>
                <col_alt>CLIENT NAME</col_alt>
                <col_alt>NAME</col_alt>
                <col_alt>NAMES</col_alt>
                <col_alt>CUST NAME</col_alt>
                <col_alt>CUSTOMER NAME</col_alt>
            </column>
            <column name="CLIENT_ADDRESS">
                <col_alt>ADDRESS</col_alt>
                <col_alt>LIVES IN</col_alt>
                <col_alt>LOCATION</col_alt>
                <col_alt>STAY</col_alt>
            </column>
            <column name="CLIENT_CONTACT_NO">
                <col_alt>CONTACT NO</col_alt>
                <col_alt>CONTACT</col_alt>
            </column>
        </table_column>
    </table>
    <table name="SALES_MASTER">
        <table_column>
            <column name="SALE_DATE">
                <col_alt>SALE DATE</col_alt>
                <col_alt>BILL DATE</col_alt>
                <col_alt>SALES DATE</col_alt>
            </column>
            <column name="TOTAL_BILL">
                <col_alt>TOTAL BILL</col_alt>
                <col_alt>GRAND TOTAL</col_alt>
            </column>
        </table_column>
    </table>
</mapping>
```

Comment: i tried using java.XML.XPath but failed to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i remember correctly Xpath expression like this should work for you. I do not have complete code to give it a try.

```
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//table/table_column/column[col_alt='SALE DATE']/@name");
Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
}
```

doc - is the document reference of the xml.

Comment: from this how can i get the @name of <table> tag

Comment: Added code to show how you will read your info. Since I do not know if  value of col_alt is unique I have used NodeSet. If you know then look at other options in XPathConstants like String etc.

Comment: Thanx, for your valuable advice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a schema for the XML? If so can you check JAXB